# reading unknown number of of integers and printing them in words

Tags: c, input, stdin

I'm trying to process input from stdin but keep running into walls.
My goal is to read a strem of numbers(0-99) and print each one in words.
My first attempt was:

```
int main(void) {

char *a[20] = {"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight",
"nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen",
"seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"};

char *b[8] = {"twenty","thirty","fourty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"};

int num=0, tens=0, ones=0;

while (scanf("%d", &num)==1){
    tens = num/10;
    ones = num%10;

    if (tens>1){

        printf("%s ", b[tens-2]);
        printf("%s \n", a[ones]);
    }
    else
        printf("%s \n", a[num]);
}
printf("done");
return 0;
}
```

Output is correct but scanf never terminates the loop.

Second attempt:

```
int main(void) {

char *a[20] = {"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight",
"nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen",
"seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"};

char *b[8] = {"twenty","thirty","fourty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"};
char line[1024], *ptr = NULL;
long num;
int tens=0, ones=0;

if(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)!=NULL){


    do {
        num = strtol(line, &ptr, 10);
        tens = num/10;
        ones = num%10;

        if (tens>1){

            printf("%s ", b[tens-2]);
            printf("%s \n", a[ones]);
        }
        else
            printf("%s \n", a[num]);
    }while (*ptr!= '\n');
}

printf("done");
return 0;
}
```

Here I get a compilation error and can't find the problem so I don't know if it works.

[UPDATE]: The second code runs but for an input of more then one number like
12 35 51 it prints the first number (twelve) infinitely.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the compilation errors?

Comment: id returned 1 exit status.

Comment: what? It's not a compilation error..

Comment: Your first snippet is "fine" (unless you enter a number greater then 99 or a negative one), try input a letter instead of a number and the loop will stop. The second snippet works too (once you add `#include <stdio.h>`), it reads one number only.

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY post that as answer

Comment: 1) "Output is correct but scanf never terminates the loop."  --> `scanf()` return value depends on what the user typed in.  The user input is not listed in the post.  By providing the input used, the problem will be easier to solve.  2) "Here I get a compilation error "--> posting the error is helpful too.

Comment: BTW: [forty vs fourty](http://grammarist.com/spelling/forty-fourty/)

Comment: @chux 1. for input like: 12 52 31 
output is:
twelve
fifty two
thirty one 
but the program doesn't end and keep waiting for more input.
I know scanf ignores whitespace so that's the problem I'm trying to solve
2. I got it to run but the problem is with the use of strtol, I get the first number from the string I pulled from input over and over again and it doesn't move on to the next part of the string

Comment: @Elad Nadav  note: "I know scanf ignores whitespace" is incorrect.  It depends on the format passed to `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close. You just need to validate the return of `strtol`, and update the pointer address based on the `endptr` following the call to `strtol`. You should also check for values outside the range of your conversion as mentioned in the discussion. This is all that is needed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {

    char *a[] = {"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six",
                 "seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve",
                 "thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen",
                 "seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"};

    char *b[] = {"twenty","thirty","fourty","fifty","sixty",
                 "seventy","eighty","ninety"};
    char line[1024] = "";
    long num;
    int tens=0, ones=0;

    if (fgets (line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL) {

        char *p = line, *ep = NULL;
        errno = 0;

        while (errno == 0) {
            num = strtol (p, &ep, 10);      /* convert to long  */
            if (p == ep) break;             /* no digits, break */
            p = ep;                         /* update p to ep   */
            if (num < 0 || 99 < num) {      /* validate range   */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: %ld - out of range.\n", num);
                continue;
            }
            tens = num/10;
            ones = num%10;
            if (tens > 1) {
                printf ("%s ", b[tens-2]);
                printf ("%s \n", a[ones]);
            }
            else
                printf("%s \n", a[num]);
        }
    }

    printf ("done\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/n2string
12 55 61 -1 33 102 4
twelve
fifty five
sixty one
error: -1 - out of range.
thirty three
error: 102 - out of range.
four
done
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you. one thing I don't fully understand, why do I need to use another pointer, isn't "p" and "line" both pointing to the start of the string?
In writing this code I followed several examples that used line as the first parameter in strtol. Is it different when you use strtol several time in a loop? or more fundamentally during the execution of this code how do "p" "ptr" and "line" change  from their initial values

Comment: You need a second pointer for `strtol`. If you look at *man strtol*, its declaration is `long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);` Where `nptr` points to the string to be converted, and `endptr` is updated to the first position *after* conversion (if a conversion takes place). To convert more than 1 number per-line, you convert the first, and then check `(nptr != endptr)` to insure a conversion took place, and then set `nptr = endptr` (`p = ep` in my example) so you are pointing to the character *after* the number you converted so you can convert the next.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the code appears to be to print the text version of a digit that was entered. Your code works almost unchanged, I just added a library and ran it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    char *a[20] = {"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight",
                   "nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen",
                   "seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"};

    char *b[8] = {"twenty","thirty","fourty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"};
    char line[1024], *ptr = NULL;
    long num;
    int tens=0, ones=0;

    if(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)!=NULL){


        do {
            num = strtol(line, &ptr, 10);
            tens = num/10;
            ones = num%10;

            if (tens>1){

                printf("%s ", b[tens-2]);
                printf("%s \n", a[ones]);
            }
            else
                printf("%s \n", a[num]);
        }while (*ptr!= '\n');
    }

    printf("done");
    return 0;
}
```

**Test**

```
19
nineteen 
done
```

Maybe the problem was that you didn't know the purpose of the code.

Comment: I wrote that code so I know its purpose, try giving it an input of more then one number like: 12 25 58
The loop prints 12 infinitely
My problem seems to be in getting the next number in the string pulled from input